# SingleCellExperiment. Why I'm not succeeding in change rownames and colnames in my single cell experiment?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I have to manipulate some data in order to get insight about adenocarcinoma. In order to get more insight I have to manipulate my data. Until now my pipe line is as follows :

```
nsclc <- read.table("D:\\Bioinformatica\\Project Work and PhD Proposal\\Data\\Data Extracted\\GSE143423_lbm_scRNAseq_gene_expression_counts.csv",
header=TRUE,sep=",")

meta_1 <- read.table("D:\\Bioinformatica\\Project Work and PhD Proposal\\Data\\Data Extracted\\GSE143423_lbm_scRNAseq_metadata.csv",
header = TRUE,sep =",")

meta_1$X <- NULL
#......Creation of first Single cell Experiment

sce_lc <- SingleCellExperiment(
assays = list(counts = as.matrix(nsclc)),
rowData =nsclc[1:dim(nsclc)[1],1] %>% data.frame ,
colData = cell <- paste0("cell_",1:dim(nsclc)[2]) %>% data.frame,metadata = meta_1)
```

when I explore **sce_lc** experiment no change in rownames is observed as well as it is for colnames.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please properly format your  code and if possible, make your problem reproducible by including at least a snippet of the data in an easy-to-paste form.

Comment: I 'll work on it as soon as I can!

Answer (score 2):

You need to name the rows of your matrix. read the [vignette](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/SingleCellExperiment/inst/doc/intro.html) before embarking on your journey. rowData and colData are something else. You can just specify the rownames and colnames of your matrix before slotting them in. And avoid the pipes when creating the object.. some of the assignments are really weird:

```
library(SingleCellExperiment)

nsclc = data.frame(what=paste0("gene",1:100),
matrix(rnbinom(1000,mu=100,size=1),ncol=10,nrow=10))
meta_1 = data.frame(id=1:10,var=letters[1:10])

rownames(nsclc) = as.character(nsclc[,1])
colnames(nsclc) = paste0("cell_",1:ncol(nsclc))

sce_lc <- SingleCellExperiment(
assays = list(counts = as.matrix(nsclc[,-1])),
metadata = meta_1)

class: SingleCellExperiment 
dim: 100 10 
metadata(2): id var
assays(1): counts
rownames(100): gene1 gene2 ... gene99 gene100
rowData names(0):
colnames(10): cell_2 cell_3 ... cell_10 cell_11
colData names(0):
reducedDimNames(0):
spikeNames(0):
```